# Matrix Representation and Lie Algebra basis of a product of Lie Groups

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

- Is there a principled way to find the matrix Lie group (representation) and Lie Algebra basis of the product of multiple Lie groups? 
  In particular, and as an example, say $G = \mathrm{SE(3)} \times \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathrm{SE(3)}$.

Comment: If this is a direct product, then its Lie algebra is the direct product of the Lie algebras of the factors.

Comment: So it's not possible to put them in a bigger matrix for the entire group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Lie algebra, Ado's theorem gives a faithful linear representation $\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ for some $n$. Of course, if $G=G_1\times G_2$ is already linear, then we can represent  $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \mathfrak{g_2}$ by block matrices, and take the natural representation for the linear Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_2$. In the example here, $SE(3)$ is already a linear Lie group. A basis for its Lie algebra is given [here](http://www.xrpbot.org/wiki/SE3).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the relationship between direct sum and block matrices which makes it possible. Also, does that mean I can compute the adjoint independently and assemble one big adjoint matrix for the direct sum (block-wise)?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.